# After installing mysql-server, and doing $mysql, mysql won't start. Mysqld.sock missing

Tags: login, mysql

First, I installed mysql-server

Next, I did

> $mysql

I was going to add a database and edit some stuff.

But I got this error:

> ERROR 2002 (HYOOO) : Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

How do I fix this? Thanks for your time

Edit #1: I did this command:

> $sudo service mysql start

And I got this back:

> start: Unknown Job: mysql

Help?

Comment: try to go into sudo before logging in mysql. Also look at tutorials or use mysql --help to se how to log into db.

Answer (score 0):

By default MySQL seems to only listen on a TCP socket, rather than a unix domain socket.

Your client is trying to connect to the server over the (faster) domain socket.

You need to enable the unix socket like so:

Edit the file:

/etc/mysql/my.cnf

Uncomment the line:

socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Then run:

## service mysql restart

Comment: Just to be sure, do we uncomment be doing something like */this is an uncommented line/*

Comment: I keep on getting more errors, like "/usr/bin/service: 127: /usr/bin/service stop: not found